# ALE remove permanent echo on problem line

Tags: plugin-ale

### Information

**VIM version**
VIM - Vi IMproved 9.0 (2022 Jun 28, compiled Mar 16 2023 00:00:00)
Included patches: 1-1407

Operating System: Linux (Fedora 38,Gnome)

### What went wrong

From the last update of ALE (through vim-plug) I am getting a permanent warning line after eol of a problematic line, even when my cursor is far from it. Please see the screenshot [image]

As you can see, even when my cursor in not around the problem line, I am getting the error/warning msg.
I want only the preview window when the cursor is on it. This is happening for python and fortran.

This is my ALE settings:

```
g:ale_sign_error = ''
g:ale_sign_warning = ''
g:ale_sign_info = ''
highlight ALEErrorSign guibg=#00A56A guifg=#ffffff ctermbg=NONE ctermfg=red
highlight ALEWarningSign guibg=#00A56A guifg=#ffffff  ctermbg=NONE ctermfg=yellow
# let g:ale_set_loclist = 1
# let g:ale_set_quickfix = 0
g:ale_fix_on_save = 1
g:ale_fixers = {
      \ '*': ['remove_trailing_lines', 'trim_whitespace'],
      \ 'tex': ['latexindent', 'remove_trailing_lines', 'trim_whitespace'],
      \ 'python': ['isort', 'yapf'],
      \ 'cpp': ['astyle', 'clangtidy', 'remove_trailing_lines', 'trim_whitespace'],
      \ }
g:ale_linters = {
      \ 'fortran': ['gcc'],
      \ 'tex': ['texlab'],
      \ 'python': ['pycodestyle'],
      \ 'vim': ['vint', '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vim-language-server/bin/index.js'],
      \ 'cpp': ['ccls'],
      \ }
```

#### :ALEInfo

```
 Current Filetype: python
Available Linters: ['bandit', 'cspell', 'flake8', 'flakehell', 'jedils', 'mypy', 'prospector', 'pycln', 'pycodestyle', 'pydocstyle', 'pyflakes', 'pylama', 'pylint', 'pylsp', 'pyre', 'pyright', 'refurb', 'ruff', 'unimport', 'vulture']
  Enabled Linters: ['pycodestyle']
  Ignored Linters: []
 Suggested Fixers: 
  'add_blank_lines_for_python_control_statements' - Add blank lines before control statements.
  'autoflake' - Fix flake issues with autoflake.
  'autoimport' - Fix import issues with autoimport.
  'autopep8' - Fix PEP8 issues with autopep8.
  'black' - Fix PEP8 issues with black.
  'isort' - Sort Python imports with isort.
  'pycln' - remove unused python import statements
  'pyflyby' - Tidy Python imports with pyflyby.
  'remove_trailing_lines' - Remove all blank lines at the end of a file.
  'reorder-python-imports' - Sort Python imports with reorder-python-imports.
  'ruff' - A python linter/fixer for Python written in Rust
  'trim_whitespace' - Remove all trailing whitespace characters at the end of every line.
  'yapf' - Fix Python files with yapf.
 Linter Variables:

let g:ale_python_auto_pipenv = 0
let g:ale_python_auto_poetry = 0
let g:ale_python_auto_virtualenv = 0
let g:ale_python_pycodestyle_auto_pipenv = 0
let g:ale_python_pycodestyle_auto_poetry = 0
let g:ale_python_pycodestyle_executable = 'pycodestyle'
let g:ale_python_pycodestyle_options = ''
let g:ale_python_pycodestyle_use_global = 0
 Global Variables:

let g:ale_cache_executable_check_failures = v:null
let g:ale_change_sign_column_color = 0
let g:ale_command_wrapper = ''
let g:ale_completion_delay = v:null
let g:ale_completion_enabled = 0
let g:ale_completion_max_suggestions = v:null
let g:ale_disable_lsp = 0
let g:ale_echo_cursor = 0
let g:ale_echo_msg_error_str = 'Error'
let g:ale_echo_msg_format = v:null
let g:ale_echo_msg_info_str = 'Info'
let g:ale_echo_msg_warning_str = 'Warning'
let g:ale_enabled = 1
let g:ale_fix_on_save = 1
let g:ale_fixers = {'tex': ['latexindent', 'remove_trailing_lines', 'trim_whitespace'], '*': ['remove_trailing_lines', 'trim_whitespace'], 'cpp': ['astyle', 'clangtidy', 'remove_trailing_lines', 'trim_whitespace'], 'python': ['isort', 'yapf']}
let g:ale_history_enabled = 1
let g:ale_history_log_output = 1
let g:ale_keep_list_window_open = 0
let g:ale_lint_delay = 200
let g:ale_lint_on_enter = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_filetype_changed = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_insert_leave = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_save = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_text_changed = 'normal'
let g:ale_linter_aliases = {}
let g:ale_linters = {'vim': ['vint', '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vim-language-server/bin/index.js'], 'tex': ['texlab'], 'cpp': ['ccls'], 'fortran': ['gcc'], 'python': ['pycodestyle']}
let g:ale_linters_explicit = 0
let g:ale_linters_ignore = {}
let g:ale_list_vertical = 0
let g:ale_list_window_size = 10
let g:ale_loclist_msg_format = '%code: %%s'
let g:ale_max_buffer_history_size = 20
let g:ale_max_signs = -1
let g:ale_maximum_file_size = v:null
let g:ale_open_list = 0
let g:ale_pattern_options = v:null
let g:ale_pattern_options_enabled = v:null
let g:ale_root = {}
let g:ale_set_balloons = 1
let g:ale_set_highlights = 1
let g:ale_set_loclist = 1
let g:ale_set_quickfix = 0
let g:ale_set_signs = 1
let g:ale_sign_column_always = 0
let g:ale_sign_error = ''
let g:ale_sign_info = ''
let g:ale_sign_offset = 1000000
let g:ale_sign_style_error = ''
let g:ale_sign_style_warning = ''
let g:ale_sign_warning = ''
let g:ale_sign_highlight_linenrs = 0
let g:ale_statusline_format = v:null
let g:ale_type_map = {}
let g:ale_use_neovim_diagnostics_api = 0
let g:ale_use_global_executables = v:null
let g:ale_virtualtext_cursor = 'all'
let g:ale_warn_about_trailing_blank_lines = 1
let g:ale_warn_about_trailing_whitespace = 1
  Command History:

(executable check - success) pycodestyle
(finished - exit code 1) ['/bin/bash', '-c', '''pycodestyle''  - < ''/tmp/vuFsWop/1/i.py''']

<<<OUTPUT STARTS>>>
stdin:1:1: W391 blank line at end of file
<<<OUTPUT ENDS>>>
```

Comment: Did you consider going through the plugin's documentation?

Comment: I tried my best to go through the documentation, specially ale_echo* plugins. I am not sure what i am missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change `g:ale_virtualtext_cursor`:

```
let g:ale_virtualtext_cursor = 1
```

More information with: `:help g:ale_virtualtext_cursor`

Comment: So the solution was in the doc all along? Incredible.

Comment: Vimquisitor you are too sarcastic :-)

Comment: The documentation is good, but a bit confusing at first. It was not obvious that these comments are called "virtual text". Then `:help virtualtext` landed me on `g:ale_virtualtext_delay` and the correct option was described above in the help page, under `g:ale_virtualtext_cursor`. This question and answer helped me add `let g:ale_virtualtext_cursor = 0` to my `.vimrc`. Thank you.